# change how prefilled email address shows (XCode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

In my app i am pre-filling the email address when the user wants to email someone. i do this like this:

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"sales@microsmith.com"];
NSString *subjectStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"test subject"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailController setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[mailController setSubject:subjectStr];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
[mailController release];

[subjectStr release];
```

this all works fine with no problems. However, i wanted to know if there was a way to change what showed in the "To:" field once the email opens.

For example, instead of showing - sales@microsmith.com, i would like it to show "Microsmith Sales".

Is that possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, just change the way your recipient strings are formatted:

```
NSArray* recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"Sales Dept <sales@example.com>"];
```